# Understanding How to write test data in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework and going through its documentation. In Robot Framework's overall test data syntax they state the below example:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Example using the space separated plain text format.
Library          OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${MESSAGE}       Hello, world!

*** Test Cases ***
My Test
    [Documentation]    Example test
    Log    ${MESSAGE}
    My Keyword    /tmp

Another Test
    Should Be Equal    ${MESSAGE}    Hello, world!

*** Keywords ***
My Keyword
    [Arguments]    ${path}
    Directory Should Exist    ${path}
```

I am unable to understand what **[Documentation]  /  Example test and [Arguments]    ${path}** in respective sections means - there does not seems to be a clear explanation for same?

How can I learn these basics syntax as the guide does not starts from basic **"Hello World"** program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Overview

Values in square brackets in a test case or keyword definition are called *settings*. They are documented in the robot framework user guide in the sections titled [Settings in the test case table](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#settings-in-the-test-case-table) and [Settings in the keyword table](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#settings-in-the-keyword-table).

Robot supports a fixed number of settings, so you can't just put any word you want inside square brackets. Anything in the first word of a line that is in square brackets will throw an error if it's not one of the supported settings.

Test cases support the settings `[Documentation]`, `[Tags]`, `[Setup]`, `[Teardown]`, `[Template]`, and `[Timeout]`

Keywords support the settings `[Documentation]`, `[Tags]`, `[Arguments]`, `[Return]`, `[Teardown]`, and `[Timeout]`

### [Documentation]

As you surmised, `[Documentation]` is for setting the documentation for a test case or keyword. More information can be found in the robot framework user guide, in a section titled [Test case name and documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-case-name-and-documentation) and [User keyword name and documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#user-keyword-documentation)

The advantage to using `[Documentation]` instead of comments is that the documentation will appear in reports and logs, and will be included in documentation generated by [libdoc](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#libdoc) and [testdoc](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-data-documentation-tool-testdoc).

### [Arguments]

`[Arguments]` are how you specify arguments to a keyword. You cannot use this setting for test cases. It is only available for keywords, and is documented in a section titled [User keyword arguments](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#user-keyword-arguments)

For example, if you write a keyword that accepts the arguments "first_name" and "last_name", you would define the `[Arguments]` setting like this:

```
*** Keywords ***
Example Keyword
    [Arguments]  ${first_name}  ${last_name}
    log  Hello, my name is ${first_name} ${last_name}
```

Within the keyword, the first argument will be assigned to the local variable `${first_name}`, and the second argument will be assigned to `${last_name}`.